# Include attachments per default when forwarding mail

Tags: mutt

Currently, I include each attachment manually when forwarding mail with Mutt.

As described [here](http://micronerds.org/mutt/#forwarding-attachments), I do this by tagging the individual attachments and then forward them using `;f`.

Is there a way to make Mutt include all attachments per default when forwarding a mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [`mime_forward`](http://mutt.org/doc/manual/#mime-forward) setting. Forwarding as attachment will include the whole message (attachments included) as a MIME encapsulated message.

More information about forwarding options [here](http://mutt.org/doc/manual/#forwarding-mail).